# Stripe TLS update issue in updated coldfusion version 11

Tags: java, coldfusion, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, tls1.2

I am trying to charge the card using stripe but I am getting this error.

[image]

I am using coldfusion 11 with java version 1.7.0_55. I have checked the server for any updated but there is no update. I have searched it a lot but no success till now.

The token is generating but when I try to charge the card this error shows.

I am using this cfc

```
"https://pastebin.com/UKfpe23D"
```

Is there any solution??

Comment: You should consider upgrading the JRE/JDK to Java 1.8 u131.  It may solve the SSL cipher issue by having the latest version running.  I'm running JRE 1.8 u131 on my ColdFusion 11 servers and it is working very well. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a JVM argument you can configure in the CF admin (adobe CF 11) that will force CF to use TLS 1.2. You'll have to verify the syntax but it's something like:

```
-Dhttps.protocol=TLS1.2
```

That should fix your issue (assuming you have access to the CF admin)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, should I add this to the end of jvm arguments?

Comment: i am waiting for your reply.

Comment: It is not usual for an answer to take a while. But I think that this should be added to the JVM arguments. Don't forget to backup the config file first.

Comment: Yes, that goes into jvm.config file. Make a backup first before making the changes. Also, restart CF after making the changes. If this doesnt help, then look at updating the JDK to 1.8.